# Homestead.yaml file not adding project folder in vagrant | Mac os

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I am using mac os and just install vagrant and configured homestead.yaml file but after `vagrant up` command also tried `vagrant reload --provision`

Also database not created in mysql.

Here is my homestead.yaml file

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 3048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/myname/mytest
      to: /home/vagrant/mytest

sites:
      - map: mytest.local
      to : /home/vagrant/mytest/public

databases:
    -  mytest
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

to add path we need to add ~(tilde) sign it refers as a home directory in mac.

updated yaml file.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 3048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/myname/mytest
      to: /home/vagrant/mytest

sites:
      - map: mytest.local
      to : /home/vagrant/mytest/public

databases:
    -  mytest
```

Comment: I pretty much doubt `~/myname/mytest` is equivalent of `/Users/myname/mytest`, because of how `~` works it would then be `/Users/myname/myname/mytest`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i thought also but in my case tilde sign path is working

Comment: What i am saying is that these are NOT equivalent ao you have different path and tilde makes no difference